# AJAX call return Unexpected token ILLEGAL on GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use AJAX on GET call, but chrome console show me an error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL".

```
function go_API(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.video2mp3.at/settings.php',
           data: {
           set: "check",
           format: 'mp3',
           id: "VYsSw06AZRI",
           key: 201813
           },
           dataType: 'jsonp',
           success: function(msg) {
                console.log(msg);
           }
           });
}
```

The data returned is

```
OK|2|9d6e363b378df616e4677c0738d3827b|Sandra Echeverria-Nos volveremos a ver(LYRICS)|NO|
```

I saw that several had this problem, but in datatype: json, nothing approaching my code. So.. What's wrong?

Comment: The value returned by `http://www.video2mp3.at/settings.php` is not a valid `jsonp` response... so try `dataType: 'json'`, if the said resource is not supporting cross domain request then you may have to use your web server as a proxy server to get the 3rd party content